# Is it safe to delete files in the WINDOWS\pchealth\ERRORREP\UserDumps\ folder?

Tags: windows

I have files in `C:\WINDOWS\pchealth\ERRORREP\UserDumps\` getting close to 100 MB each.  Is it safe to delete them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PCHealth folder contains data as part of the Microsoft Help Center Service. The hdmp files are the large, uncompressed dumps from the crashing program. The mdmp files are the compressed dumps that are sent to microsoft.

**As these are just files being used for debugging, you can delete them all safely.**

If your userdumps folder continues to gain these files, then your system is having problems. Any application that crashes will leave these dump files. You will have to figure out the problem before these files will stop being created.

[Source](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2640/xp_delete_userdumps_hdmp_restore_massive_amounts_hard_drive_space/)

Answer (score 3):

You can delete them safely, and you can stop them being created in future by:

1. Right-click, "Properties" on "My Computer". (Or press Winkey+Pause)
2. Select the "Advanced" tab
3. Under "Startup and recovery" frame, click "Settings"
4. Set "Write debugging information" to "(none)".